# CSV to JSON in Python takes only first and last rows

Tags: python

I made a function that converts data from given csv file to a json object, and the weird thing is that it only gets the first and last element of the CSV.
My csv structure is 2 columns: name,days

Example:

```
name,days
John,17
Fred,2
Michelle,22
```

When I get the json object, and print it, it gives me:

```
jsondata is:  {
"0": {
    "name": "John",
    "days": "17"
},
"1": {
    "name": "Michelle",
    "days": "22"
}
```

}

Here is my code:

```
data = {}
with open(file, "rt") as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
    i = 0
    for rows in csvReader:
        data[i] = rows
        i =+ 1
jsondata = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print("jsondata is: ", jsondata)
```

Comment: You use the wrong operator/syntax to add to `i` - use `+=`  not `=+`

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I made that typo! Thank you! Please feel free to publish an answer so other people can start verifying these typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why would you need to use `i` as a counter but here a two suggestions:

```py
data = []
with open(file, "rt") as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

    for rows in csvReader:
        data.append(rows)

jsondata = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print("jsondata is: ", jsondata)
```

or

```py
data = {}
with open(file, "rt") as csvf:
    csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)

    for i, rows in enumerate(csvReader):
        data[i] = rows

jsondata = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print("jsondata is: ", jsondata)
```

In both cases you will be able to access by index e.g.: `data[0]`, `data[1]`...